# How to handle a question that has (wrong) answers on a different question?

Tags: discussion

[What determines the max CP and which methods are there to predict them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/275456/88641) has been marked as possible dupe.

While I'd argue it is a different question the dupe suggestion also contains answers that would satisfy my question. But they are additional notes, which the OP wasn't technically asking for, while they are still related to the question.

But as all who play it know: niantic isn't that straight with presenting its game mechanics. So all the answerers are using as resource are their own impressions. Where comes the part I'm now not quiet sure about how to act. (If my case shoudl come out to be diferent from the former description please answer for the situation I'm describing and not the acutal case.)

I would like to get an answer that is evaluating the behavior or even better refering to a trustworthy resource. that is actually none of the answers doing. So they even could be wrong and one day a correct answer comes and isn't addressing the part I'm askign for, leaving my post as dupe of that one while it is only containing wrong answers about my OP.

So the question now is:

Should my OP anyway be marked as dupe and while that post is asking for topic A and Containing answers for topic A and B, should I add a bounty asking for adding resources on topic B? while thats not even what OP was itnerested in?

Or should in this case my post stay seprated as OP?

Comment: How do you know it's wrong?  If your question is asking the same thing, it's a dupe.  Answers don't even come into the equation.  If you don't like the answers, that's what bounties are for.

Comment: @Frank: Well I just did know from Stackoverflow that there it is a valid reason for beeing a dupe if there is a completely diferent questionw hich contains answers that are answering my question. SO I assumed beeing here the same. if thats not the case this whole thing is unrelated and can be closed. I also don't know if they are wrong, but I can feel free to assume it in case they can't show any resource except arguing about their own impressions, can't I? And this is jsut asking about what would be the right way, placing a bounty on a question that asks a diferent thing? or do it as I did?

Comment: If you're asking the same thing, it's a dupe.  From a quick look, your question is actually two different parts, one asking the same thing as what it's currently marked as a duplicate of, and another one regarding the size.  It looks like you want more expanded answers on how CP works, but that's still a duplicate; the answers not providing the information you want is why you should bounty it, as that's not a reason to re-ask it.

Comment: @Frank: What about handing that in as answer?